# version compability between spark and kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am updating spring boot from `1.5` to `2.3` and kafka from `0.11.0.3` to `2.5.0` Is spark `1.6.3` compatible with kafka `2.5.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 2.3+ has upgraded its internal Kafka Client and deprecated Spark Streaming; I suggest upgrading, and not stating an explicit dependency on `kafka-clients`, as it is included by `spark-sql-kafka` dependency.

Kafka Clients newer than 0.10.2 will continue to work for basic functions against newer brokers.